# Debian Bookworm doubles the ISO Size?

Tags: debian

I downloaded the new Debian Bookworm image and found that it is twice the size of its predecessor (Bullseye).

[image]

Can someone explain to me why the image is so huge all of a sudden?

Comment: I voted to migrate your question to https://unix.stackexchange.com/ as I expect that you're more likely to get a high quality answer there than on ServerFault

Comment: it's still one cd. I don't see an issue inhere, it may due the new Firmware Feature